# Popover requires tooltip.js

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

What could be causing this 404 error, it seems like it only might be coming from ios devices:

Requested URL: /post/415-7-ways-hide-survival-garden/Popover requires tooltip.js
User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25

NOTE: Using Bootstrap v3.1.1

Comment: I actually just did that late last night. The problem is that even before updating bootstrap I was unable to replicate the issue. I guess I'll just have to wait and see if I get any 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Popover docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

> ## Plugin dependency
>
> Popovers require the tooltip plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: is it not included with bootstrap by default?

Comment: It is included by default. `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` contains ALL of Bootstrap's plugins. If you're using the individual plugin files, you want `bootstrap/js/tooltip.js`.

Comment: I am using the full distribution.